Why is the generator not trained directly in GAN
When we build a GAN network we usually do the following:

Build a discriminator and compile it
Build a generator
Build a combined model generator+discriminator and compile it

Now for training we do the following:

Train the discriminator on fake an real images
Then put some noise into the combined model and train the generator via the error obtained from the combined model

My question is:
Why do we need the „combined model“? For me the straightforward way to train a GAN is to compile the generator and let it output some images, then put them into the discrimination and calculate the loss. With that loss we train the generator directly.
However, what is done in practice is that we never separately compile the generator but only the „combined model“. Therefore the gradients have to flow through the discriminator first to reach the generator in backward-propagation. And this is something which seems odd to me. Why not use the discriminator loss directly?
Relating to this: what about adding an additional loss (e.g. MSE for a super resolution task)? It makes no sense to me to add this loss to the „combined model“ loss but rather use it directly as the generator loss and just add an additional loss from the discriminator (MSE+adversial loss).
